# Replacing PermissionManagementComponent

Tags: angular, abp

In trying to replace PermissionManagementComponent in abp angular framework project in my project I receive the following errors.

1.Module '"@abp/ng.permission-management"' has no exported member 'GetPermissionListResultDto'.
2.Module '"@abp/ng.permission-management"' has no exported member 'PermissionGrantInfoDto'.
3. No suitable injection token for parameter 'service' of class 'PermissionManagementComponent'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

How will I resolved this errors as I'm new in Abp framework with Angular 15

Comment: What are you trying to replace with PermissionManagementComponent. Can you elaborate more? You can checkout the StackOverflow guidelines on how to ask a questions here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.